# Excel - Conditional Group By ID

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following sample data:

[image]

I would like to use a formula or vba to modify the `final` column by group based on the following conditions:

- For each `id`, if any value in the `valid` column is `false`, all values in the `final` column should be false.
- For each `id`, if all values in the `valid` column are `true`, all values in the `final` column should be true.
- For each `id`, if `text` is not blank, all values in the `final` column should be false.

I've tried using index matching:

```
=$A1=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("true",$B:$B,0))
```

But am not sure how to apply this to a group.

The desired result from the sample data would be:

[image]

Thank you for any assistance! I am not proficient with Excel and hope to learn from this.

Comment: I've tried matching on index but am at a loss about how to apply the conditions to group by `id`: `=$A1=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("true",$B:$B,0))`

Comment: You should include your efforts in the post. I would use vba but if Scott's around, he can whip up a formula in seconds.

Comment: `=(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,FALSE)+
      COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$C$2:$C$10,"*"))=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=NOT(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=A2)*(($B$2:$B$10=FALSE)+LEN($C$2:$C$10)>0)))
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]